# Is $\omega(x,y,z)=(y^2+2xz^2)dx+(2xy+2y^2z^3)dy+(2x^2z+3y^3z^2)dz$ Exact?

Tags: calculus

$$\omega(x,y,z)=(y^2+2xz^2)dx+(2xy+2y^2z^3)dy+(2x^2z+3y^3z^2)dz$$ on $\mathbb{R^3}$

I have took

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(y^2+2xz^2)=2y$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(y^2+2xz^2)=4xz$$

And

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2xy+2y^2z^3)=2y$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(2xy+2y^2z^3)=6y^2z^2$$

And

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x^2z+3y^3z^2)=4xz$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2x^2z+3y^3z^2)=9y^2z^2$$

Due to the face that there is no $$\frac{\partial}{\partial j}\omega_y = \frac{\partial}{\partial i}\omega_z$$

It is not closed and therefore not except (poincare lemma)?

Comment: And you seem to make a mistake in the calculation, especially the middle two.

Comment: @ArcticChar Sorry, used too many copy paste in the equations